# JavaScript If/Else statment for range slider user input of HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take user range slider input into a HTML form and then call a java function for further execution. Till the calling of JavaScript function it works fine but it by default consider only first `if`.

I want it to execute the if statement if the range slider input is greater than of equal to 100 or else if slider input is less than 100.

## HTML Code

```
<tr height=40>
    <td width=40></td>
        <td>
        <form id="P1_pulsetime" oninput="">
            <br><br>
            10<input type="range" id="port1_pulseslider" min="10" max="120" value="20" onchange="pulserangevalueX.value=value"/>120
            <output id="pulserangevalueX">20</output>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="Port1_pulsetime()" value="Port_1_pulse">
            <br><br>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

## JavaScript

```
function Port1_pulsetime(){
        if(connected_flag==1){
            client.subscribe("lazy/test");
            var P1_slider = document.getElementById("port1_pulseslider").value;
            var pulserangevalueX = document.getElementById("pulserangevalueX").value;

            if (pulserangevalueX >= '100') {
                message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("port1_pulseslider").value);
                message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
                client.send(message);
                }
            else if (pulserangevalueX < '100') {
                message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 10" + document.getElementById("port1_pulseslider").value);
                message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
                client.send(message);
                }
            }
        else {
            console.log("not connected")
            }
        return false;
    }
```

I think there is some minor error which I am unable to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing an else as shown below, insert a console.log() to see if it enters the else.

```
function Port1_pulsetime(){
    if(connected_flag==1){
        client.subscribe("lazy/test");
        var P1_slider = document.getElementById("port1_pulseslider").value;
        var pulserangevalueX = document.getElementById("pulserangevalueX").value;

        if (pulserangevalueX >= '100') {
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("port1_pulseslider").value);
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            }
        else if (pulserangevalueX < '100') {
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 10" + document.getElementById("port1_pulseslider").value);
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            } //INSERT ELSE HERE
              else {
              // INSERT CONSOLE LOG HERE
            }
        }
    else {
        console.log("not connected")
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it works the same and by default executing 1st if statement.

Comment: so by default always entering "not connected" ?

Comment: No ,by default it execute only this function:if (pulserangevalueX >= '100') {
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("port1_pulseslider").value);.it should compare the value and execute accordingly.